# problems with infinite loop

Tags: php, infinite-loop

```
function addAds($n) {
 for ($i=0;$i<=$n;$i++) {
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users"))) {
   $aut[]=$row['name'];
  }
  $author=$aut[rand(0,mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users")))];
  $name="pavadinimas".rand(0,3600);
  $rnd=rand(0,1);
  if($rnd==0) {
   $type="siulo";
  } else {
   $type="iesko";
  }
  $text="tekstas".md5("tekstas".rand(0,8000));
  $time=time()-rand(3600,86400);
  $catid=rand(1,9);
  switch ($catid) {
   case 1:
    $subid=rand(1,8);
    break;
   case 2:
    $subid=rand(9,16);
    break;
   case 3:
    $subid=rand(17,24);
    break;
   case 4:
    $subid=rand(25,32);
    break;
   case 5:
    $subid=rand(33,41);
    break;
   case 6:
    $subid=rand(42,49);
    break;
   case 7:
    $subid=rand(50,56);
    break;
   case 8:
    $subid=rand(57,64);
    break;
   case 9:
    $subid=rand(65,70);
    break;
  }
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO advert(author,name,type,text,time,catid,subid) VALUES('$author','$name','$type','$text','$time','$catid','$subid')") or die(mysql_error());
 }
 echo "$n adverts successfully added.";
}
```

The problem with this function, is that it never loads. As I noticed, my while loop causes it. If i comment it, everything is ok. It has to get random user from my db and set it to variable $author.

Comment: **You have a SQL Injection vulnerability**.

Comment: @SLacks, no they don't. All of the values are being pulled from the database or generated in the function. The only thing that seems like any problem at all could be the users table, but that's still a stretch.

Comment: @Brendan Long - Just because the value comes from the DB doesn't mean it's clean. Within the scope of the question, what's to stop a row in `users` from having a `name` of `','','','','','','');insert into table sql_injection_attacks values (TIME());`?

Comment: Whether it's possible or not doesn't really matter, everyone should just do database stuff safely all the time rather than spend a second thinking "wait, **could** this be dangerous?"

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen - But now you're just assuming. How many people are doing to allow punctuation like that in their user names? It's certainly possible, but from this function alone you can't just say "There's an SQL injection vulnerability".

Comment: @Brendan Long - I beg to differ; rather, _you_ are assuming based on the fact that the column is named `name`. From this function _alone_, one can _only_ conclude there is an SQL injection vulnerability; there is no information to suggest otherwise. Even if you are right about the intent of the `name` column, a DB has its own username/password and can be comprimised independantly of the code.

Comment: @SLacks, this function is just for testing. It will be deleted when my project will be open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the query is in the loop, so it gets run every time (so you start from the beginning every time). Just move the mysql_query() part to right before the while loop and store it in a variable:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
```

Answer (score 4):

**You can replace this mega switch with one line:**

```
$subid = rand(($catid * 8) - 7, min($catid * 8, 70));
```

Comment: @Gumbo: Thinking about this randoms, i think is a good approx ;-) But if they dont want aproxx they can add to this 3 lines and get 100% reflection. 4 lines is better than 29.

Comment: Well, since it’s using `rand` you could also just write `$subid=4;`. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The condition of a `while` loop is executed and evaluated with each iteration. So `mysql_query` is called with every iteration and retunrs true.

Just execute your database query once and cache the result:

```
function addAds($n) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
    $aut = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $aut[]=$row['name'];
    }
    $rowCount = count($aut);
    for ($i=0; $i<=$n; $i++) {
        $author=$aut[rand(0,$rowCount)];
        // …
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO advert(author,name,type,text,time,catid,subid) VALUES('$author','$name','$type','$text','$time','$catid','$subid')") or die(mysql_error());
    }
    echo "$n adverts successfully added.";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also think the problem is your functions are way too big to understand(quickly). You should make them smaller and test them with a unit testing framework like phpunit.

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot of time that I don't use PHP but I think that the assignment

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users"))
```

should always returns `true`, it executes the query again and again on every iteration..

Answer (score 0):

You're starting a new query each time you run the loop.